# Using Paramiko in Kivy App

Tags: python, kivy, paramiko, buildozer

I'm working on an kivy app for android.
To implement ssh communication I chose paramiko.

I'm using buildozer to build the apk and deploy it on android devices.

My project works fine on ubuntu, unfortunately not on android.

I would really appreciate any kind of help, I'm stuck and don't know how to move on. Thank you in advance.

Building the package with buildozer works, but when I deploy the app to my android device, the app crashes and I get the following error with logcat:

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

```
I/python  (17300): Initialize Python for Android
I/python  (17300): Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
I/python  (17300): /data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app
I/python  (17300): Preparing to initialize python
I/python  (17300): crystax_python does not exist
I/python  (17300): Initialized python
I/python  (17300): AND: Init threads
I/python  (17300): testing python print redirection
I/python  (17300): Setting up python from ANDROID_PRIVATE
I/python  (17300): ('Android path', ['/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app/lib/python27.zip', '/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app/lib/python2.7/', '/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/', '/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/', '/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app'])
I/python  (17300): ('os.environ is', {'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/storage/emulated/legacy', 'LOOP_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/obb', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '9', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/core-libart.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okhttp.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/mms-common.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/sec_edm.jar:/system/framework/sagearpolicymanager.jar:/system/framework/secocsp.jar:/system/framework/seccamera.jar:/system/framework/timakeystore.jar:/system/framework/commonimsinterface.jar:/system/framework/imsmanager.jar:/system/framework/secEmailBC.jar:/system/framework/knoxvpnuidtag.jar', 'ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE': '8,0', 'PATH': '/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET': '/storage/emulated', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'PRIMARY_STORAGE_TYPE': 'internal', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyo', 'SECONDARY_STORAGE': '/storage/extSdCard', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app:/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app/lib', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE': '/mnt/shell/emulated', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'LEGACY_STORAGE': '/storage/emulated/legacy', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app', 'INTERNAL_STORAGE_TYPE': 'emulated', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app'})
I/python  (17300): ('Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is', '__main__')
I/python  (17300): ['/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app/lib/site-python']
I/python  (17300): AND: Ran string
I/python  (17300): Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
I/python  (17300): [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 19)
I/python  (17300): [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-06-30_0.txt
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Jun 29 2017, 18:03:55) 
I/python  (17300): [GCC 4.8]
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <ARM>
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mali-400 MP>
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
I/python  (17300): [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
I/python  (17300):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  (17300):    File "/home/andi/Desktop/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 55, in <module>
I/python  (17300):    File "/home/andi/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myappnew/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
I/python  (17300):    File "/home/andi/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myappnew/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 57, in <module>
I/python  (17300):    File "/home/andi/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myappnew/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/ed25519key.py", line 17, in <module>
I/python  (17300):    File "/home/andi/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myappnew/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
I/python  (17300):  ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myappnew/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/_bcrypt.so" has unexpected e_machine: 3
I/python  (17300): Python for android ended.
```

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

My buildozer.spec file:

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = MyAppNew

# (str) Package name
package.name = myappnew

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
#requirements = python2, kivy, sqlite3, paramiko, plyer, 
#requirements = python2, sqlite3, kivy, plyer, ecdsa, cryptography, bcrypt, paramiko
requirements = python2,sqlite3,kivy,datetime,plyer,ecdsa,cryptography,bcrypt,paramiko

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 2

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,CAMERA

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

Comment: You have found the solution to this problem?